# How to wrap long text inside a div without scroll

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width:200px; margin:0 auto;"> 01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969798991001011021031041051061071081091101111121131141151161171181191201211221231241251261271281291301311321331341351361371381391401411421431441451461471481491501511521531541551561571581591601611621631641651661671681691701711721731741751761771781791801811821831841851861871881891901911921.........
</div>
```

The above code is showing a long scrollbar. I want to keep it inside the div's declared width (`width: 200px;`) without scrolling. 
I have tried float, display, position, overflow, but nothing works here.

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap onto 2 or more lines? Please clarify.

Comment: @MarcAudet - Yes I need all the text but inside the width of "200px"

Comment: What is the *actual* content? A meaningless string of digits followed by periods and preceded by a space? What are the permissible points where the string may be broken? This *heavily* depends on the content and its context, and as an abstract question, this is either “unclear what you are asking” or “too broad” (if one would cover even a dozen common scenarios, the answer would be too long for the SO format).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:-

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/thyD9/

Comment: This will force the content to be break to multiple lines.

Comment: @IbrahimAshShohail Well, OP didn't specify how he wants the text to be handled, be it wrapping to the next line or trailing with ellipses or what.

Comment: And that's why I commented. So that he understands the effect of this CSS bit. :)

Comment: @IbrahimAshShohail Ah, gotcha. I just saw a quick downvote on it, then your comment came in. Thought you were being a jerk. :P

Answer (score 10):

Alternative you can use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`. Also avoid inline styles.

**css**

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Firefox support */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukLGz/2/)

Comment: `overflow-wrap` is not fully supported in FireFox.  `word-wrap` is much better supported.

Comment: Yes, for firefox use `word-break: break-all;` or `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */   
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**Note:** Avoid `inline` styling.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/65EJw/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:200px; margin:0 auto; word-wrap:break-word;">    01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969798991001011021031041051061071081091101111121131141151161171181191201211221231241251261271281291301311321331341351361371381391401411421431441451461471481491501511521531541551561571581591601611621631641651661671681691701711721731741751761771781791801811821831841851861871881891901911921.........
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Emr84/

Answer (score 0):

Try with these CSS rules

```
 white-space: nowrap;      //keep the text on one line
 overflow: hidden;         //prevent the text from being shown outside the border
 text-overflow: ellipsis;  //cut off text with an elipsis
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Full explanation: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html

Answer (score 0):

for me following worked, my div was inside a scrollable parent div, just add to your child or content div

```
    div{
        white-space: normal;
        }

OR

    div{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```